# Can UCWA retrieve the scheduled Microsoft Outlook meetings?

Tags: outlook, lync, ucwa

> I am specifically interested in the OUTLOOK Meeting information and
>   NOT ONLINE MEETING.

Can I GET the outlook calendar meetings (along with its details: time, subject, location, attendees, etc) using UCWA.

I asked about the same on UCWA forum of MSDN, and came to know that it isn't possible via UCWA.
However, this raises another question:
As a Lync user, if I hover my mouse over a contact who's busy in a meeting, then it shows the time until when he/she is busy, for example "Busy until 2 p.m.".

How is Lync fetching this outlook meetings information and displaying the output as per the meeting time. How does this mechanism work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lync/Skype for Business clients are making requests via Outlook APIs to grab non-online-meeting events to display that data.  You would need to design your application to sign-in to their Outlook account and make use the available [Outlook APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations) to get all the meetings/appointments that are not present in Lync/Skype.